# Custom growl SDK subscriber feed notification creation error

Tags: .net, feed, growlnotify, growl-for-windows

Using Growl for Windows.

I'm trying to implement a custom feed subscription plugin, similar to the RSS/Atom Feed Subscriber. Been searching the forums but can't seem to find any useful info.

I have downloaded the Growl Subscriber SDK, and implemented a solution in .NET, VS 2010. I get the plugin to "install"/growl to pickup the plugin, but am quite stumped as to what to enter as the "feed url".

So I suppose my question is "How do I create my own feed to which a client could subscribe"?

For example, having implemented a custom forwarder application, using the Custom Forwarder SDK, I attempt to enter something like: `$http://localhost:2751/Home` as the URL but get an error "Could not parse feed".

This should be helpful for anyone else trying to implement a custom subscriber using growl for windows

Any help much appreciated!

EDIT:
Have checked google forums, "growl for windows".
SDK downloaded from: [Growl for windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/developers.aspx)

EDIT 2:
Seem to have misunderstood the problem a bit. There seems to be a difference between sending notifications, receiving notifications, and subscribing to a feed. The feed needs to be a RSS feed, which one needs to create :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my response in the Growl for Windows discussion group - I think there is a bit of a misunderstanding on what the various parts are used for. https://groups.google.com/group/growl-for-windows/browse_thread/thread/ed330b8e15a91b83?hl=en